# Slow loading Rails 5.1.4 with Ruby 2.3.3-p222

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have standard view with 1 database query (MySQL). I am using `Devise` and method for checking is it user logged in `layouts/application.html.erb`:

```
<% unless user_signed_in? %>
    <%= render 'partials/login_modal' %>
    <%= render 'partials/registration_modal' %>
<% end %>
```

Layout is with 4 partials included (_header.html.erb and _footer.html.erb, too). All generated HTML (from html tag to html) is around 320 lines.

In production I set :
`config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = false`.

The site loads really slow, but only the first time, right after starting server and it doesn't matter which page loads. It is same for all . If I load page stop and start server again and reload page, it is slow, but after first time loading after server is started, it loads page normal.

In `production`:

- FontAwesome loads for 20ms;
- the CSS file for 8ms,
- JS file - 14 ms and three images around 10-20ms each.

The page which is 11Kb loads for more than 9 seconds.

In `development`, same page, I have different requests for assets (9 CSS/JS/img files, each between 20 -50ms for loading) and same page (11.4Kb) loads for more than 11 seconds.

I read in the console when it s `development` mode:

> Started GET "/contacts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-10-12 23:33:48 +0300
>
> (1.0ms)  SET  @@SESSION.sql_mode = CONCAT(CONCAT(@@sql_mode, ',STRICT_ALL_TABLES'), ',NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO'),  @@SESSION.sql_auto_is_null = 0, @@SESSION.wait_timeout = 2147483
>
> (1.0ms)  SELECT `schema_migrations`.`version` FROM `schema_migrations` ORDER BY `schema_migrations`.`version` ASC
>
> Processing by ContactsController#index as HTML
>
> Rendering index.html.erb within layouts/application
>
> Rendered index.html.erb within layouts/application (1.0ms)
>
> Rendered partials/_header.html.erb (1.0ms)
>
> Rendered partials/_footer.html.erb (0.0ms)
>
> Rendered partials/_login_modal.html.erb (1.0ms)
>
> Rendered partials/_registration_modal.html.erb (0.0ms)

I am using Windows 10, but is same on `Ubuntu`. It is same and if I upload site to `Heroku` and only first time when browser loads the site.

Answer (score 1):

Rails load all your Javascript and CSS in cache browser at the first request. After what it using [turbolinks](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) for simulate an Single page app.

That's why your first request is slow, but not other. It's an implementation choice made by rails team.

But in your case, 9 and 11sec it's really slow. Can I have a link to your website on Heroku ?

Comment: Hi, i can't provide my app, but I make test and I see it is not only my. For the example I created new app. The page which is by default loads normal (around 1 second), but I create controller Test with method index and empty view index, again it loads for around 7-10 seconds, right after server starting (I am restarting server with `heroku -a restart my_app`). You can check it here - https://tytyo.herokuapp.com/test/index